# Using TextBox inside GridView gives error "'TextBox' is not delared" in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to read the values of each TextBox but get an error saying:
'TextBox2' is not delared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Code in front:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="equipment_note" SortExpression="equipment_note">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the even simpler code behind:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strTextBoxValue1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim strTextBoxValue2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim strTextBoxValue3 As String = TextBox3.Text
    Response.Write(strTextBoxValue1)
End Sub
```

The 'Dim strTextBoxValue1 As' etc line works fine, but value2 and value3 both show the same error saying they're not declared.

How do I read/retrieve the values from TextBox2 and TextBox3 in the code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the textboxes/server controls in the grid directly instead you need to access the rows thoes aur populated are going to populated like in DataRowBound event.

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Display the company name in italics.
        Dim TextBox1 As TextBox = e.Row.FindControl("TextBox1") As TextBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just edited the "code behind" paste above to show how it works when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Adil I think you are mixing up your VB and C# :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that cause you have one textbox for each row. You'll need to loop the rows to get to value of each one of them.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    strTextBoxValue2 = CType(row.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Text
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Adil said you need to find the control first and then you can transfer the value to somthing.
example:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(i)
        Dim strTextBoxValue2 as string = CType(row.Cells(0).FindControl("TextBox2"), Textbox).Text
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestion, but the word 'row' is throwing the same error as above, "is not delared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." - do I need to add something else too?